# Where's Websphere Clustering?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I've downloaded WAS 8.5 trail for Windows, in order to prepare for an application server migration; I cannot find, as documented in IBM Red Book, the option **Servers > Clusters** which could be used to manage a WAS cluster.
Do I need to download an additional product, or simply clustering it's not available without a license ? That could be a pity since I'd need testing an application on WAS clustering before deciding if we can get rid of other issues we currently have with another application server. 
Thanks
Max

Comment: Which version did you download ? You need ND (Network Deployment) version to have access to clustering options

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've started to download ND and see if I'm able to integrate it with my WAS trial. Just one further info: as far as you know, if you are running a fully-licensed WAS, do you get a single bulk product with Network Deployment integrated ? or do you still have to combine the two products to get cluster working ? Thanks

Comment: Two products, you can see ND part as a featured pack ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ND (Network Deployment) version to have access to clustering options